# preg_match issue to retrieve data from table

Tags: php, preg-match

```
 <h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;" class="margint15 marginb15">Headlines</h3> 
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nc" width="100%"> 
     <tr>
        <th class="left" colspan="2">Latest Headlines</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="left" width="620"> <a href="/blogs/rhb/79680.jsp" style="color:#06a;">Trading Stocks - 10
     July 2015 - Globetronics | A&M | Salcon | Comintel | Homeritz |
     MMSV</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract the data from the tag "" which the class="nc" until the end of the tag "". How to write the pattern for preg_match?

Comment: want to extract the data from the tag "table" which the class="nc" until the end of the tag "table". How to write the pattern for preg_match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, this has been discussed here like a thousand times, [better not use some regular expression to grab html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (there may be cases in which in works quite well though). For the sake of the christmas spirit, here's an example for your purpose (scraping financial data of a site that is not yours ;-)) Consider using an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead:

```
<?php
$str='<container>
<h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;" class="margint15
marginb15">Headlines</h3>  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
border="0" class="nc" width="100%"> <tr><th class="left"
colspan="2">Latest Headlines</th></tr> <tr><td class="left" width="620"> <a
href="/blogs/rhb/79680.jsp" style="color:#06a;">Trading Stocks - 10
July 2015 - Globetronics | A&amp;M | Salcon | Comintel | Homeritz |
MMSV</a> </td></tr></table>
</container>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
print_r($xml);

// now you can loop over the table rows with
foreach ($xml->table->tr as $row) {
    // do whatever you want with it
    // child elements can be accessed likewise
}
?>
```

**Hint:** Obviously, I made up the `container` tag, it's likely to be `html` in your case.

**Appendix:** As [Scuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61795/scuzzy) points out, make yourself familiar with xpath ([here's a good starting point](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/12/3/3/searching-and-filtering-with-xpath)), the combination is extremely powerful.

Comment: And making use of [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) is amazingly powerful to locate content.

Comment: @Scuzzy: Added your comment to the answer, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Scuzzy Though blatantly off-topic, how's the weather in good old Brizzy?

Comment: Thank you, it's a better solution which reminds me to improve my previous  code! Anyway, regExp is really hard to understand. :)

Comment: @Jan quite good at the moment, mix of 30c days and rain here and there.

Comment: Also, here's some code that might help if you've got bad HTML to parse, returns a new simplexml object... `function simplexml_import_html($html){$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');libxml_use_internal_errors(true);$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'),LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);libxml_clear_errors();return simplexml_import_dom($dom);}`

Comment: Thanks, Scuzzy!! I have a strong feeling that your function is really cool, but please forgive me if I failed to call your function..would you mind to give example? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should go with this:

```
$str = '<h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;" class="margint15 marginb15">Headlines</h3><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nc" width="100%"> <tr><th class="left" colspan="2">Latest Headlines</th></tr> <tr><td class="left" width="620"> <a href="/blogs/rhb/79680.jsp" style="color:#06a;">Trading Stocks - 10 July 2015 - Globetronics | A&M | Salcon | Comintel | Homeritz | MMSV</a> </td></tr></table>';
preg_match_all('/<table.*?>(.*?)<\/table>/si', $str, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( strip_tags($matches[1][0]) );
die();
```

Thanks!

Comment: But I just need the table with the class "nc". Thanks!